# Little Snitch reports my app (when run in simulator) wants to connect to random websites

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, afnetworking

I have an app that uses a web service to get data.  I hit one site for the data, passing in various parameters/methods depending on what data I need.  The base URL of the site is always the same.  I'm using AFNetworking whenever I get/receive data.

When I launch my app in the iOS simulator, Little Snitch indicates that my app wants to connect to a couple of sites - sites that are not in my code!

Example sites Little Snitch has indicated:

www.tv.com
common.publicradio.org

Anyone know why this happens?

**EDIT:**

I'm only hitting some Cold Fusion methods at http://www.acquisign.com no other sites.  The Acquisign site has no links to any of the mentioned sites.  I load no web pages, just get JSON back from the CF methods invoked at the Acquisign site.

**EDIT 2:**

More info:
I've fond that this has to do with OpenDNS.  If I set my network to not use OpenDNS, I don't get these random connection warnings from Little Snitch and my app.  (Today it wanted to connect to home depot.com and relish.com).

OpenDNS is most likely responding to a non-loading page request with a page of link suggestions.  I now wonder what the non-loading page is - as I only hit one site and get JSON back and the JSON contains no other URLS....

Comment: Maybe if you post a little more information, such as what is the site where you're calling these web services? Maybe the web service is supplying URLs that are on those other sites. You could also post some code showing how you're retrieving the data.

Comment: I'm guessing that some of the data returned contains links to those sites.

Comment: I bet those URLs you're loading are in turn loading content from other domains, this will certainly be the case if you're loading actual webpages.